# zend framework 2 return $this->rediect()

Tags: zend-framework2

ex1:

```
// do something ...
return $this->redirect()->toRoute(..);
return false;
```

ex2:

```
public function myTest(){
     return $this->redirect()->toRoute(..);
}

// do something ...

myTest();
return false;
```

When do I use ex1, my code stopped and return, didn't run return false;
the same code below ex2, return false ran.
Please help me, why such ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in **ex1** `return false;` is not being reached because `return` exits the function you're currently running in. So calling `$this->redirect()->toRoute(..)` will run, then execution will end for that function.

in **ex2**, you're defining a function `myTest()`, so the `return $this->redirect()->toRoute(..);` exits the `myTest()` function with the return value of `toRoute()`.

Then the next line of code, `return false` runs and exits the function it resides in with the value of `false`.

Once you call return, any code following that statement will be ignored. Sort of like a `break;` or `continue;` statement in a for loop.

You would need to add logic, like an `if` or `switch` statement and determine whether you want to `return false` or `return $this->redirect()->toRoute(..);`.

For example:

```
function someFunction() {       // someFunctionCalled
    if (codingIsFun) {          // Coding is fun
        $foo = myTest();        // $foo is true, since myTest() returns true.
        return $foo;            // Exit "someFunction()" with a return value of $foo (true)
                                // any remaining code in "someFunction()" will not be executed.
    }

    // Some people will put this line in an "else" block,
    // but it isn't necessary, this code will only execute if 
    // coding is not fun.
    return false; // Coding is not fun.
}

function myTest() {
    return true;
}


// Call someFunction, if coding is fun, $isCodingFun will == true,
// If not, $isCodingFun will == false.
$isCodingFun = someFunction();
```